# Delete kinks and smooth curves

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting, smoothing, interpolation

I have some data which when plotted looks like the one shown in left on the picture attached.
It has some kinks which I wish to delete and smooth-en to get a nice curve [shown on right].

Presently I manually delete the kinks and interpolate the deleted part by polynomial of high order [say 9]. Then I repopulate the deleted fragment and re-draw the curve.
This takes a long time and I have quite a number of files to process.

Could you folks suggest an efficient way to do this ?
[in MATLAB or some other way][image]

Thanks a lot !!

P.S.: Added one more plot for clarification above
[image: Second case]

Comment: look at the moving average example in the `filter` function documentation, it may helps you.

Comment: Thanks I will look at it. But I think I tried it once and the results were not very satisfactory if the data had huge kinks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a simple low pass filtering problem like @thewaywealk suggests. Removing the kinks corresponds removing certain high frequencies in your signal. This can be achieved in matlab by the filter operation. Demonstrations are shown here on [denoising a sinusoidal wave here](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/digital-filtering-in-matlab/).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot definitely. The only thing I am worried about it if I had a large kink, suppose a step or a depression created in the data for a considerable duration: say 15% of total range of x-axis. Then it will be very difficult to automate smoothing.

Comment: Just added one more plot to explain what I mean to convey.Thanks again.

Comment: In this case i would suggest a wavelet thresholding approach that performs smoothing at different scalings of the wavelet basis. This is demonstrated in [matlab](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/dsp/examples/wavelet-denoising.html) too/ This is exactly for the case where the kinks occur at different scales in your x dimension.